# Trying to add Firebase to iOS app, but can't add Initialization Code

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, appdelegate

I am currently following the steps to add Firebase to an iOS app on this link: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/fir-198a3/overview

I have been able to follow the steps successfully until reaching the part where I need to add the "initialization code". It states that I need to add the code below the main AppDelegate class. But in my .xcworkspace file (the one created after adding the Cocoapods using terminal) I don't see any of the code that I have on my original one.

My question is then: What should I do to add to connect Firebase when your app starts up?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
content_copy

This is the code I am supposed to copy: (I am running the latest Xcode version)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
content_copy

    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/ for a detailed overview of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this, to connect to Firebase when your app starts up:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What file do you put that code in though, index.js?

Comment: I recommend you do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  without knowing the basics you will not go very far in coding an App, and you will not be able to understand the answers you get from your questions. **Understand the very basics first.**

Comment: mac user here. If you are using vs code& project of react native and need to process the step upon, go to your project -> ios file -> your projectname's file -> AppDeletegate.mm and add -> [FIRApp configure]; in the file . can refer to https://rnfirebase.io/ , step : Configure Firebase with iOS credentials

Answer (score 0):

React Native App **File ./ios/../AppDelegate.mm**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  // Other config ...
}
```